# Building debuginfo RPM at alternate prefix

Tags: rpm, debug, specfile

I have an RPM that I'm building to install at an alternate root via

```
%define _prefix /home/other/root
```

This works fine for the binary package.

The -debuginfo package, however, still lists all of its files as being in `/usr/lib/debug` and `/usr/src/debug` .

How do I create the -debuginfo package so that its files are instead in `/home/other/root/lib/debug` and `/home/other/root/src/debug` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That being said it looks like those paths may be hardcoded in the find-debuginfo.sh script. So you would either need to edit that or find a way to move the files around in the buildroot and modify the file containing the file list that the script creates.

As per daxelrod's comment (and some documentation searching now that I have the time to do that). In order to get gdb to see the source and debugging symbols in your location correctly you would need to use gdb commands like [directory](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html) (to set the source directory) and to set the [debug-file-directory](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html) appropriately.

Other details about the debug file location searching are included in that last link as well.

Comment: Yes, I'm building a package at an alternate root because I don't want to provide it to the system, but to a self-contained application bundle.

Comment: You can specify alternate locations to gdb with `directory` and `symbol-file`.